# Jsoup won't give me a complete list of what I ask

Tags: java, list, jsoup

I use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse a HTML page and when using `doc.select("tr")` it should place return a list with all `<tr>` elements. When I investigate the size of that list it tells me 242. Although when using Chrome to double check against the source with a simple search, it got 264 hits.

This makes my code break. It seems almost like jsoup doesn't handle a lot of Elements very well.

I'm parsing a page with a table, 262 * 88 cells and almost as many helper tags. Is this the reason why jsoup doesn't have the objects in the list? Or why do you think I'm having this problem?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Without any code or any clue about the markup it's impossible to help.

Comment: @Kim Kling...Did you ask nicely?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a differance in the websites. You often get a different view if you have a desktop browser, than e.g. a mobile device.

You can try this with jsoup:

1. Set a user agent of a browser
2. Print the parsed document (`System.out.println(doc)`) and check if all tags are included
3. Check the website using another browser
4. Check if there's no javascript (or similar) which creates additional html (jsoup can't handle those)